# how merge 2 column and seperate them by ,?

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanna merge the following columns

```
   p    t
   1    2
   3    4
   2    5
```

output:

```
  m
  1,2
  3,4
  2,5
```

Comment: use ``paste0()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
with(df1, paste(p, t, sep=","))
```

Or with `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
unite(df1, m, p, t, sep=",")
```

Comment: how we can separate a column with 4,3 entries to 2 columns ?  opposite of my question!

Comment: @user9272398. You can use `separate(df1, m, c('p', 't'), sep=",")`

Answer (score 1):

Akrun's solution is excellent but I also like to do it with `data.table` if you're are using this package.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(dt)
dt <- dt[, m := paste0(p, ",", t)][,c(3)]
```

Output :

```
     m
1: 1,2
2: 3,4
3: 2,5
```